How to Use GitHub Copilot Device Flow Sign-In in Visual Studio 17.10 or Later?
I recently updated to Visual Studio 17.10 and noticed that the option to sign in with GitHub Copilot using the device flow is no longer available. I have two GitHub accounts and subscribing to Copilot for both is too expensive.
Is there any way to still use the device flow sign-in method in Visual Studio 17.10 or later, or any alternative method to manage multiple accounts without incurring additional costs?

Go to Tools -> Options -> Github -> Copilot
There will be a setting called "Sign in with Device Flow".  Set it to true.
Close Visual Studio.  Re-Open it.
Go to Edit -> Copilot Suggestions -> Sign in with Device Flow
If the menu is disabled, sign into your github account via Visual Studio and repeat the above process again.  Once VS is restarted, you should see a Copilot message in the message bar near the top of the app.  That will guide you with completing the rest of the setup.
EDIT: 08-03-2024
If you don't see the Tools -> Options-> Github -> Copilot menu, you need to install the feature using the Visual Studio installer.  In the installer, go to the "Individual Components" tab and search for "Copilot", then check the box.  There is also an option called "Include Github Enterprise Server Accounts" under the Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Accounts menu.  Ensure that box is checked as well.

But that option is no longer there any more.

What option is no longer there?  Are you speaking of Tools -> Options -> Github -> Copilot?  If that's the case, see my edited answer above

I can't find the device flow either. VS 22 17.11.3 Comunity Ed.

@Pepik Looks like the latest update removed the "Device Flow" menu (sigh)
