How to access github copilot in vscode on linux
I installed vscode on linux by downloading the tar.gz, unzipping it and copying it to /my/path
Then I run it: /my/path/bin/vscode
So far so good. When I try to access copilot, it sends me to github.com, but the redirection with the path (https://vscode.dev/redirect) does not open copilot again and I can never access it. What can I do?
Distro: Manjaro Linux
Browser: Edge Version 129.0.2792.89
Full Redirect URL: https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvscode.dev%2Fredirect&scope=user%3Aemail&skip_account_picker=true&state=vscode[xyz]

When I hit Open, nothing happens

I see there may be a third option for signing in github inside of vscode called "device code flow": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78765247/how-to-use-github-copilot-device-flow-sign-in-in-visual-studio-17-10-or-later This may offer a way through the issue without directly addressing the issue you are facing.

I also see some talk of the same issue affecting Manjaro here: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cant-open-vscode-url/77934 where the folks replying are suggesting that it may be a mime/mapping issue. If this is the issue it's not clear to me if it's a manjaro thing or a kde thing.

@JNevill It doesn't work, I removed vscode from the mimetypes list, also Tools -> Options -> Github -> Copilot is a Visual Studio path, not vscode
